# Python self not allowing append for lists

Tags: python, list, class

So, I am making a Python project, and I have a class with two `self` variables, a list named **names** and one named **vals**, then in a later method, I need to append a name and a value to the lists, but I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    redwire.vars.create("name", redwire.main.recieve("Name? "))
  File "/home/runner/RedWire/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redwire/__init__.py", line 28, in create
    self.names.append(name)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'names'
```

Below is my code for the class, any help is appreciated.

```
class vars:
    def __init__(self):
      self.names = []
      self.vals = []
    def create(self, name, val=0):
      self.names.append(name)
      self.vals.append(val)
```

Comment: You are calling this like ```vars.create('name', 2)``` which is the problem, it should be ```vars().create('name', 2)```. Also you shouldn't overwrite the built-in python function ```vars()```

Comment: Don't edit the question and add an answer.  On SO, upvote helpful answers and accept the best one below (if any) by selecting the check to the left and give the answerer some rep.  Also note your code doesn't produce the error message.  Make sure to include a [mcve] that when copied and execute actually produces the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you instantiated the class?

```
class Vars:
    def __init__(self):
        self.names = []
        self.vals = []
    def create(self, name, val=0):
        self.names.append(name)
        self.vals.append(val)

redwire = Vars()
redwire.create("name", 123)
print(redwire.names) # ["name"]
print(redwire.vals) # [123]
```

Comment: Thanks! I tested this and it has worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Can you mark the answer as accepted?

Comment: @What_do_we_do_now please read [what to do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).